# Steps for making Yii::t() work with extensions in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have created an extension called GalleryManager, stored in the extensions directory of the application.
I have this structure:

```
gallerymanager
|--  assets
|--  messages
|    |-- en
|    |    |-- main.php
|    |-- es
|    |    |-- main.php
|    GalleryManager.php
```

My GalleryManager class (defined in GalleryManager.php) is like:

```
class GalleryManager extends CApplicationComponent{...
```

This is what the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPhpMessageSource) says about defining Categories for translation:

> Messages for an extension class (e.g. a widget, a module) can be
>   specially managed and used. In particular, if a message belongs to an
>   extension whose class name is Xyz, then the message category can be
>   specified in the format of 'Xyz.categoryName'. And the corresponding
>   message file is assumed to be
>   'BasePath/messages/LanguageID/categoryName.php', where 'BasePath'
>   refers to the directory that contains the extension class file. When
>   using Yii::t() to translate an extension message, the category name
>   should be set as 'Xyz.categoryName'.

So, I am trying a line like this in a view:

```
<?php echo Yii::t('GalleryManager.main', 'Add');?>
```

And it doesn't work. 
What else do I have to do in order to make Translations work for a Yii Extension?

Comment: Shouldn't you have your messages in `protected/messages/` ?

Comment: @AliMasudianPour no, according to the documentation, by default `messages` directory should be stored inside the directory that contains the class file (which in my case is what I have showed in the dir structure)

Answer (score 1):

Everything you have done is correct and according to the documentation.

Are you sure you are declaring the extension properly in the main config? you should have in there:

```
'components' => array(
            /* load extension */
            'GalleryManager' => array(
                'class' => 'app.extensions.GalleryManager',
            ),
```

I sometimes do not load extensions like this myself (because this still work otherwise), but for messages to work I believe you have to declare it in the config too.

Comment: Yes, i am declaring it in `components` section of `config/main.php`, but like this: 
`'components' => array(
            /* load extension */
            'gallerymanager' => array(
                'class' => 'app.extensions.gallerymanager.GalleryManager',
            ),`

Is it wrong?

Comment: That looks good, can you try <?php echo Yii::t('gallerymanager.main', 'Add');?> to see if it works? (notice I do not use GalleryManager but gallerymanager). I do believe it might be case sensitive and your folder is called gallerymanager not GalleryManager.

Comment: Try defining by hand the handler for CPhpMessageSource. See more details http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPhpMessageSource#extensionPaths-detail and http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/695-how-to-use-cphpmessagesource/page__view__findpost__p__3746. In your config you should have 
'messages'=>array(

                        'class'=>'CPhpMessageSource',
'extensionPaths' => array(
    'GalleryManager' => 'app.extensions.gallerymanager.messages',
)

                ),

)